# Pulling Advanced Custom Fields from other pages

Tags: plugins, php, ajax, advanced-custom-fields

Basically I am using Advanced Custom Fields and have an ajax tabbing system that works with the ACF.

The current set up is below:

```
<ul class="css-tabs">
      <li><a class="current" href="/wp-content/themes/blue-and-grey/uni-general.php">General</a></li>
      <li><a href="/wp-content/themes/blue-and-grey/uni-courses.htm">Courses</a></li>
      <li><a href="/wp-content/themes/blue-and-grey/uni-inthearea.htm">In the area</a></li>
      <li><a href="/wp-content/themes/blue-and-grey/uni-sportsandfacilities.htm">Sports & facilities</a></li>
    </ul>
```

At the moment, I am loading external php documents through AJAX, only problem is, the php is not loading as when echo'ing that field, it cannot be found as it is held elsewhere.

How can I use the custom fields to display what's in that page template, that is held elsewhere?

I current am using:

```
<?php echo the_field('current_students'); ?>
```

To display the field, but where it's an external PHP document, it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`the_field()` takes an optional second parameter of `$post_id`. If you know the post you want, presumably you can use that to grab the data you need.

Comment: I could try that, however it's a template that will be used across multiple pages so I cannot just put a single $post_id in, there will be tens of pages underneath this template.

Comment: @OwenO'Neill - So, you gotta pass the second parameter in your Ajax page load...

Comment: managed to do it with div's instead of loading external documents. Thank you very much though!

Comment: Owen how did you do it? I am currently trying to do the same without any luck. It would be great if you could let me know how you did it. Thanks :)